# document.querySelector with dynamically created content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that is dynamically created that is using jQuery and I am trying to use Wavesurfer.js which requires the element to be selected using `document.querySelector`. Since the elements are dynamically created using jQuery, the selector does not recognise the elements.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#audio").append('<div class="row" id="wave6" class="wave"></div>');

    $('#audio').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'div', function () {
    var id = 6;
    window['waveForm' + id] = Object.create(WaveSurfer);

    window['waveForm' + id].init({
        container: document.querySelector('wave' + id),
        waveColor: 'violet',
        progressColor: 'purple'
    });

    window['waveForm' + id].on('ready', function () {
        window['waveForm' + id].play();
    });

    window['waveForm' + id].load(id + '.mp3');
});
```

This is my code so far. `id` is assigned by jQuery when dynamically creating the elements.

Comment: Are you waiting for the document to be loaded?

Comment: @WhiteHat yes. This is all happening in document ready

Comment: you'll need to ensure that you are calling `wavesurfer.init()` **after** you add the element to the page.

Comment: editing preview code in a sec

Comment: What is this `$('#btn").` ?, check the console, does that not throw an error in your code?

Comment: The element you are adding only has an  `id` of `id="6"` not the `id="wave6"` that you are querying for, change that to `$("#audio").append('<div class="row" id="wave6" class="wave"></div>');` or change the query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88285/discussion-between-senty-and-delightedd0d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are calling `wavesurfer.init()` after you add the targeted element to the page. Something like this:

```
$('#somecontainer').append('<div id="wave1"></div>')
var id=1;

var wavesurfer = Object.create(WaveSurfer);

  wavesurfer.init({
      container: document.querySelector('#wave' + id),
      waveColor: 'violet',
      progressColor: 'purple'
  });

  wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
      wavesurfer.play();
  });

  wavesurfer.load('example/media/demo.mp3');
```

Calling `wavesurfer.init()` before you add the element (like on document.ready) will not work because the `'#wave' + id` element doesnt exist yet

Comment: When I try this, I get `Uncaught Error: Container element not found`. I am editing the code, editing the OP in a sec.

Comment: @senty  see my comment on your question

Comment: @senty see my additional comment