# Initialize WaveSurfer targeting the container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wavesurfer.js

I am trying to create waveform using wavesurfer.js for dynamically created elements using JavaScript. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = 9;

  $("#audio").append('<div class="row" id="wave' + id + '"></div>');

  $('#audio').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'div', function() {
    var selectedId = $(this).prop('id');

    console.log(selectedId);
    window['waveForm' + selectedId] = Object.create(WaveSurfer);
    window['waveForm' + selectedId].init({
      container: $(this),
      waveColor: 'violet',
      progressColor: 'purple'
    });

    window['waveForm' + selectedId].on('ready', function() {
      window['waveForm' + selectedId].play();
    });

    window['waveForm' + selectedId].load(selectedId + '.mp3');
  });
});
```

console.log displays the correct id of the element, so the selector seems to work, however wavesurfer.js gives the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.container.appendChild is not a function
```

Comment: Don't rely on the deprecated `DOMNodeInserted` event.

Comment: It seemed to work (because it seemed to get the id). What do you suggest to use instead?

Comment: It's not widely supported and was deprecated ages ago. You don't need to listen to an event. `var $appendedElement =  $('<div class="row" id="wave' + id +'"></div>').appendTo('#audio'); // do something with the appended element`

Comment: @Vohuman As this is a jQuery object, it doesn't seem to work. Now I am back to my initial error `Uncaught TypeError: this.container.appendChild is not a function`

Comment: You can use the `get()` method for getting the inner element: `var domElement = $appendedElement.get(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I was at work on break before and couldn't get into it that deep.But try not to open [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292352/document-queryselector-with-dynamically-created-content) it is better to update the question as we work through the issue (unless of course a totally different problem emerges)

The below is a functional fully commented implementation of what you are trying to do with a bit simpler of an approach.

#### Here's a [copy hosted on my server to avoid the cross domain issues](http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/wavesurfer/)

#### jQuery

```
// create a global array to hold our WaveSurfers
var WaveSurfers=[];

$(document).ready(function(){
  // add your element
  // dont give any of them ids
  $("#audio").append('<div class="row needsWave"></div>');

  // call the function we will define in a second
  // pass in the path to your file
   addWaveSurfer('http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/wavesurfer/minecraftrap.mp3');
});

function addWaveSurfer(path){
    // create instance of WaveSurfer
    var tempWavesurferObject = Object.create(WaveSurfer);
        // initialize the object 
        // ".needsWave:last" gets the last element with the class "needsWave"
        // which will be the element we just added
    tempWavesurferObject.init({
            container: $( ".needsWave:last" )[0],// "[0]" gets the DOM element from the jQuery object
            waveColor: 'violet',
            progressColor: 'purple'
          });
        tempWavesurferObject.on('ready', function () {
            tempWavesurferObject.play();
        });
        tempWavesurferObject.load(path); // load the file we passed in
    // add the WaveSurfer to the global array so we can keep up with it
    WaveSurfers.push(tempWavesurferObject);

    // below shows how to access the WaveSurfers later by stoping the playback after a few seconds
     setTimeout(function(){
          var last = WaveSurfers.length-1; // get index of last WaveSurfer element
          WaveSurfers[last].stop();
     }, 10000);

}
```

#### Html

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/master/dist/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="audio"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, JSFiddle didn't work, so I tried your code in my local machine. It seems to create the waveform element (div) but does not load the waveform (image)

Comment: You dont see the wave form in the snippet here or in the jsfiddle?  like it shows here ... http://prntscr.com/8aqydb

Comment: When I try to click on the `Run code Snippet` it gives these errors and the waveform doesn't get created either http://i.imgur.com/MGmTY8j.png . We also tried in 2 different machines (osx & linux). Also tried to run your code in our locals since the mp3 is `Forbidden`. <wave> element gets created but the waveform image does not show : http://i.imgur.com/FDxixXl.png

Comment: Weird, that is not an error with my code but some knid of error with some files being loaded by SO, but that doesnt happen on my end. What browser are you using?

Comment: We are using Chrome latest version for both osx and fedora 22

Comment: Try a different browser does it still happen, and what errors are shown in the jsFiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88324/discussion-between-delightedd0d-and-senty).

Answer (score 1):

From the [github](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js) of `wavesurfer.js`, the `container` parameter in the `init` function is described as following:

> CSS-selector or HTML-element where the waveform should be drawn. This
>   is the only required parameter.

It doesn't mention whether or not a jQuery object is accepted, so try replacing `$(this)` with `this`:

```
window['waveForm' + selectedId].init({
  container: this, // or container: '#audio'
  waveColor: 'violet',
  progressColor: 'purple'
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it seems to get into an infinite loop

Comment: Try the selector `#audio`

Comment: I successfully got rid of the infinite loop with your suggestion. It seems to create the waveform div, but waveform is not loaded